# How do I move the clock back to the right in Android Pie?

Tags: settings, clock, 9.0-pie

I have just installed Android Pie and the clock has moved from the right of the status bar to the left. Is there a setting to move it back?

Comment: There isn't a setting for it. You must have root to change it.

Comment: Without root, this substratum claims to do it. I can't test being on Oreo https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-2-xl/themes/mod-center-statusbar-clock-p-t3818726

Comment: @beeshyams Substratum requires root. Also please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem encountered by many that has upgraded into Android Pie or bought a new one with Android Pie. Luckily, this could be fixed but rooting the phone is necessary. Someone I know tried this and it worked. May this also help you, 
https://www.xda-developers.com/status-bar-clock-tweaks-android-p-root/

Comment: Adding to this, you need to have root as said, as well as substratum theme engine (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=projekt.substratum&hl=en_US) and the mod itself for editing the clock (https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-2-xl/themes/mod-center-statusbar-clock-p-t3818726)

Comment: Please mention the relevant content in your answer, instead of simply linking it. If the link expires in future, the answer would lose its usefulness. Thanks.